# Get encoder/decoder for charset string

Tags: go, character-encoding

Is there a function built-in or in a supported package to get a `*golang.org/x/text/encoding.Encoder` (`Decoder`) based on an input charset string such as `ISO-8859-1` or `ISO-8859-15`? Right now the only way I see to do it is to match it myself:

```
func getEncoderForCharset(charset string) *encoding.Encoder {
    switch charset {
    case "ISO-8859-1":
        return charmap.ISO8859_1.NewEncoder()
    case "ISO-8859-15":
        return charmap.ISO8859_15.NewEncoder()
        // etc.
    }
    panic("Unknown charset \"" + charset + "\".")
}
```

Comment: have you had a look at: https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html/charset#Lookup ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`charset.Lookup(...)`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html/charset#Lookup), which returns a [`encoding.Encoding`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/encoding#Encoding), from which you can call `NewEncoder()` and `NewDecoder()`, e.g.:

```
ss := []string{"ISO-8859-1", "ISO-8859-15", "bogus"}

for _, s := range ss {
    encoding, name := charset.Lookup(s)
    if encoding != nil {
        fmt.Printf("OK: encoding=%v, name=%q\n", encoding, name)
        // encoder := encoding.NewEncoder()
        // decoder := encoding.NewDecoder()
    }
}
// OK: encoding=&{Windows 1252}, name="windows-1252"
// OK: encoding=&{ISO 8859-15}, name="iso-8859-15"
```